# Props is empty when parsing them to component which should render props in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component 'countryFactory' fetches data from two localhost JSON REST endpoints. By console.log(countries), and (labels), I can see that the data actually exists in the countryFactory component.
However when I import countryFactory in App.js, and try to parse the component to CountryTable, the props countries and labels is empty.

I think I did this in a wrong way.

I need help for someone to clarify how I easily can get access to countries and labels in my CountryTable component. Thanks! :)

Here is my App.js class.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CountryTable from "./CountryTable";
import countryFactory from "./countryFactory";
import {Table} from "react-bootstrap";
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }


async componentDidMount() {
  await countryFactory.fetchCountries();
  await countryFactory.fetchLabels();
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="App-header">
          <h2>React, State, Fetch and Mobx</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="App-intro">
          <p>Your initial task is to fetch data from the server (see exercise for how to start it),
           and create a table below, with these data</p>          
          <CountryTable props={this.props.countryFactory}/>  
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my countryFactory.js

```
//Add imports here

const countriesUrl = " http://localhost:3333/countries";
const labelsUrl = " http://localhost:3333/labels";

class CountryFactory {

  constructor() {
    this.labels = [];
    this.countries = [];
  }

  getLabels = () => {
    return this.labels;
  }

  getCountries = () => {
    return this.countries;
  }

  async fetchCountries() {
    const res = await fetch(countriesUrl);
    const data = await res.json();
    this.countries = data;
    console.log(this.countries);
  }

  async fetchLabels() {
    const res = await fetch(labelsUrl);
    const data = await res.json();
    this.labels = data;
    console.log(data);
  }
}

export default new CountryFactory();
```

Here is my CountryTable.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import countryFactory from "./countryFactory";
import {Table} from "react-bootstrap"

class CountryTable extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }


  renderLabels() {
    const labels = countryFactory.getLabels();
    console.log(labels);
    return labels.map(label => {
      return (
      <tr>
      <th>{label.name}</th>
      <th>{label.capital}</th>
      <th>{label.region}</th>
      <th>{label.population}</th>
      <th>{label.area}</th>
      <th>{label.timezones}</th>
      <th>{label.borders}</th>
      <th>{label.tldomain}</th>
      <th>{label.currencies}</th>
      <th>{label.language}</th>
      </tr>
    )
  })
  }

  renderCountries() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <thead>
              {this.renderLabels()}
            </thead>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
export default CountryTable;
```

Comment: export default CountryFactory; you don't need 'new' or the brackets

Comment: Alright, I did this now. But how can I parse the props (countries & labels) from countryFactory to App / CountryTable?

Comment: You should return them from their functions rather than setting this.countries etc., After all, you're not using them in the countryFactory since it's just there for the retrieval.

Comment: Yes I can do that. The thing is I want to practice my understanding of parsing props, so if possible I wanted to parse both props.